# zsh function screws up prompt after exit

Tags: vim, find, zsh, prompt

I use oh-my-zsh for customization and the prompt looks like this

```
┌─[naveen@bblpt005] - [~] - [Wed Jan 11, 03:16]
└─[$] <>
```

I have defined a function in my .zshrc to find files and open them in Vim.

```
vf() {
     find . -name "$*" | xargs vi;
}
```

The function works as expected, but when I exit Vim, the prompt is screwed up, and shows up as

```
┌─[naveen@bblpt005] - [~] - [Wed Jan 11, 03:20]
                                           └─[$] <>
```

Ctrl-D and other Ctrl-key combinations stop working as well. I have to fix it using the `reset` command.

How do I modify the function so that this does not happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a command under `xargs`, its stdin is connected to `/dev/null`. `vi` is probably not expecting this. A text editor should normally be run without I/O redirection. Try this and see if it has the same effect on your terminal. I bet it does:

```
vi somefile </dev/null
```

You will want to work around this by using something other than xargs. Like this maybe:

```
vi $(find . -name "$*")
```

Comment: And besides, if you accidentally screw up the terminal (not the zsh), use `reset` to ... reset it